# Asynctask status && cancel equivalent in RxJava2 Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2, publishsubject

I am trying to learn RxJava2, and converting my AsyncTasks to Observables.

I have the following piece of code that I am trying to convert.

```
if(asyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
    asyncTask.cancel();
}
asyncTask = new CustomTask();  
asyncTask.execute(input);
```

I tried to recreate the following with Disposables.

```
Disposable currentTask;
PublishSubject input = PublishSubject.create();
```

For every input

```
if(currentTask != null) currentTask.dispose();

currentTask = input
    .map(// Network calls
         // returns CustomObject)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(result -> {
               // do work with result
               }, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, throwable.toString()));
```

However, `currentTask` is always **null**. Why? Is this the wrong way to do it??

Comment: not all `subscribe(...)` methods return a `Disposable`. Can you at least hint the params you're passing into `subscribe(...)`?

Comment: are you attempting to null out the `currentTask` at any point? Also, can you add any other place where you're using the `PublishSubject input`? I suspect you might be misusing the subject and that is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Disposable` correctly but I can only assume you're messing up somewhere with the subject. Subjects in rx can be both publishers and subscribers... and subjects don't necessarily wait until `subscribe(...)` to start emitting items. For that reason, I wouldn't suggest replacing your `AsyncTask`s with any kind of `Subject`.

You can get similar, more deterministic behavior, doing this though:

```
Observable<CustomObject> networkObservable =
            Observable.create(emitter ->
                    {
                        try {
                            CustomObject object = doNetworking();
                            emitter.onNext(object);
                            emitter.onComplete();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            emitter.onError(e);
                        }
                    }
            );

if(currentTask != null) currentTask.dispose();

currentTask = networkObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        // this next subscribe is similar to AsyncTask.execute() as it starts the stream
        .subscribe(result -> {
            // do work with result
            }, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, throwable.toString()));
```

---

Also, consider looking into [`SerialDisposable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/SerialDisposable.html) and you don't have to do those null/dispose checks

```
SerialDisposable serialDisposable = new SerialDisposable();
```

> Atomically: set the next disposable on this container and dispose the previous one (if any) or dispose next if the container has been disposed.

```
Disposable disposable = networkObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(...);

serialDisposable.set(disposable); // this will call dispose on the previous task if it exists
```